# Input type=date appears blank on android

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input type=date and when I open the page on my smartphone (Android with google chrome), the input appears blank, I don't have the clock icons. Do you know why?

```html
<input type="date">
```

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Azu there is none, the OP said it is just an input with type date. I've encountered this issue as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mikemccaughan/sjwk240g/2/ If you want to try it out, since snippets don't work on mobile browsers.

Comment: caiuse.com says that `input type=date` works on Chrome version 94. https://caniuse.com/?search=input%20type%3Ddate

Comment: On my Android, it shows a drop-down carat, and when I tap on the input it shows a calendar widget where I can enter a date...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbRiA.png

Comment: On my Android Chrome (v.94.0.4606.61) when I type on an `input type="date"` a calendar opens and I can choose a date. So it seems it works okay.

Comment: Same for me Heretic Monkey but users have non clue it's a date input they Can think it's a select because of the carat

Comment: Is there a way to add a text label on this blank input ?

Comment: Have you tried `placeholder="Tap for calendar"`?

Answer (score 5):

This is *an issue related to inconsistency between browsers*. You have little other option than to create your own label/control, and use that instead of the browser-default date-input. This means it will look uniform accross all supported platforms and devices.

My approach (demonstrated below) is ***CSS-only***, meaning it uses ***No JavaScript***, which makes it clean, and eliminates any actualisation issues which often arrise when dynamically creating elements.

### CSS-only:

```css
.date-picker {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(40, 40, 250, .1);
  min-width: 10rem;
  min-height: 2rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: .35rem;
  position: relative;
  isolation: isolate;
}

.date-picker,
.date-picker>* {
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.date-picker:hover {
  background: rgba(40, 40, 250, .28);
}

.date-picker:active {
  background: rgba(40, 40, 250, .2);
}

.date-picker:focus>input[type="date"],
.date-picker:focus-within>input[type="date"] {
  color: #00f;
}

.date-picker:focus,
.date-picker:focus-within {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .1rem #00f;
}

.date-picker>.placeholder::after {
  content: "Click for calender";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
}

.date-picker:focus>.placeholder,
.date-picker:focus-within>.placeholder,
.date-picker>input[type="date"]:valid+.placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.date-picker>input[type="date"] {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: transparent;
  font-family: serif;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.date-picker>input[type="date"]:valid {
  color: #00f !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-picker" tabindex="0">
    <input type="date" required>
    <div class="placeholder"></div> 
</div>
```